# scroll list item to bottom of screen

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

What I'm trying to do:

When a list Item is clicked, I want the list to scroll until that Item is sitting on the bottom of the screen.

What I'm currently trying:

```
            myList.smoothScrollToPosition((adapter.getView(position, view, parent)).getBottom());
```

What's happening there is that the list is scrolling all the way to the bottom, rather than to the bottom of that view.

how can I accomplish this?

if you need more code samples, just let me know :)

Comment: Some more codes will be helpful

Comment: No problem. What do want to see? It's a standard listview.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?